# Google Maps - Unable to Access KML file for KML Layer

Tags: google-maps, express, kml

I'm embedding a Google Map within a website with a KML Layer and I'm struggling with what I would think is a very basic issue.

I have a KML file on my computer that I want to add to my map as a KML layer but I don't know how to "access" that specific file. I have set the url as `url: '/../data/Bus27route.kml.xml',` and currently nothing appears on my Google Map. Right now, what is between the ' ' marks, is simply "directions" to the file "Bus27route.kml.xml" which is in the directory "data".

What should be within the ' ' marks to access a file on my computer? Or is my error in accessing this file somewhere else in my code?

Thank you to anyone who thinks they might be able to help me out! Any comments, advice, questions, etc are extremely appreciated.

```
    function initMap(lat, lng) {
  var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

  // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bus_1_map'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 12
  });

var bus27Route = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: '/../data/Bus27route.kml.xml',
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: URLs for KMLLayer must be publicly available (accessible by Google's servers).  You need to provide the complete URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to a KML file can not be done locally each service based on google it must be made by means of a publicly accessible server on the Internet. it tries to place your file on a server accessible from the internet (there are also free services)

this form google maps developer

> Your file is hosted publicly on the internet. This is a requirement
>   for all applications loading KML into a KMLLayer. Google's servers
>   need to be able to find and retrieve the content in order to display
>   it on the map - this also means that the file can't be on a
>   password-protected page.

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/#your_kml_file

Comment: I made a free website using google sites and uploaded my KML file as instructed by the developer website. My code now looks something like this however my map still shows up, but my KML layer does not `function initMap(lat, lng) {
  var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bus_1_map'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 12
  });

var bus27Route = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/kmlroute/home/kml',
    map: map
  });`

Comment: I don't understand ...could be better posti it as new a new question

Answer (score 0):

When you add a KmlLayer, Google Maps API tells to Google server "where your kml file is **on the internet**."

Then Google bot accesses to your **public server** to obtain the KML file.

After that, map tiles are generates in Google Server, then finally comes up on your map.

That's why you **have to** put your KML file in a public server.